# How to write query with prefix for table name in entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, entity-framework, database-connection

I have WPF app with Oracle DB. I use Entity Framework. Connection string:

```
DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/ora;PASSWORD=1;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=user
```

I need to connect to new DB with the same namespace, but another USER ID and PASSWORD. I can't create new connection string because USER ID and PASSWORD are unique for each user of the app. I need to run only two queries to new DB. For example

```
SELECT t.column1, t.column2 FROM "USER ID".tableName t;
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new connection string dynamically at runtime and use this one to connect to the database and run your two queries.

**How to: Build an EntityConnection Connection String:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-build-an-entityconnection-connection-string

**SqlConnectionStringBuilder Class:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx